# Why does imagecopymerge fail to load png images when loaded in different order? PHP

Tags: php

```
$result=count($ingredient);
$height=$result*100+350;
  $my_img = imagecreate( 703, $height );
  $black = imagecolorallocate($my_img, 0, 0, 0);
  $my_img1 = imagecreatefrompng("./Ingredients/topbun.png");
  $my_img3 = imagecreatefrompng("./Ingredients/bottombun.png");
  imagecopymerge($my_img, $my_img1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 700, 250, 100);
  $yaxis=150;
  $small='mustard & ketchup & mayo & bbq & brown mustard & chipotle mayo';
  for ($x=0; $x<$result;$x++) {
          $smallcheck=strpos($small, $ingredient[$x-1]);
          if ($smallcheck===false) {
          $yaxis=$yaxis+105;
          } else {$yaxis=$yaxis+38;
          }
          $my_img2 = imagecreatefrompng("./Ingredients/$ingredient[$x].png");
          imagecopymerge($my_img, $my_img2, 0, $yaxis, 0, 0, 700, 100, 100);
          };
  $last = end($ingredient);
  $buncheck=strpos($small, $last);
 if ($buncheck===false) {
          $yaxis=$yaxis+105;
          } else {$yaxis=$yaxis+38;
          }
  imagecopymerge($my_img, $my_img3, 0, $yaxis, 0, 0, 700, 100, 100);
  imagecolortransparent($my_img, $black);
  $my_img4 = imagecreate(703, $yaxis+103);
  imagecopymerge($my_img4, $my_img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 703, $yaxis+103, 100);
  imagecolortransparent($my_img4, $black);
  imagepng( $my_img4, "./burgerpics/".$data[0].".png" );
  imagedestroy($my_img4);
```

This is a code I have designed to create a png image of a burger based upon user input. The code was working great, but then I included a new ingredient (lettuce). When I put lettuce on top of the burger patty, the burger patty disappears. When the lettuce is underneath the burger patty, they both appear fine.

I thought that it may have to do with file size, as lettuce is the largest ingredient file I have created (27.6KB). I am not convinced though, because that is still an incredibly small file.

Any ideas about what may be causing this?

[Lettuce on top of burger patty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKNFS.png)

[Lettuce under burger patty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLuAy.png)

Comment: Does your lettuce have any extra white space underneath it that could be causing it to overwrite the patty?  Do any of the images use an alpha channel (transparency)?

Comment: byte size of a compressed image file is mostly irrelevant. a 10,000 x 10,000 pixel image can compress down to just a couple hundred bytes, but still requires 300+ megs of ram to store in memory while working with it.

Comment: My lettuce does not have any extra white space underneath it.  All the images are given an alpha channel of 100 with imagecopymerge.

Comment: Marc - Could it be my internet connection speed or perhaps my web host? I am using AwardSpace and have unlimited disc space and traffic.

Comment: I edited my code to destroy the images after I have merged them, and now the burger patty is showing up. Now my issue is that it is green, rather than the color it is supposed to be.